# ipv4 address vs localhost

Tags: tcp, localhost, ip

if our system IP address acts as a local host, then what does this definition indicates for IP address of localhost - "127.0. 0.1 is the loopback Internet protocol (IP) address also referred to as the localhost"

Answer (score 0):

Within a network every device has it's own ip address. The ip address of a device is for every device different and May change (DHCP).
The hostname loclalhost respectively the ip address 127.0.0.1 points always on the current device.

For example If you are using a laptop and ping from that laptop to 127.0.01 it will resolve to the  device the ping is send from thus the laptop itself.
If you ping from a server, it will resolve to the device the ping is send from thus the server.